# How to insert ref objectId in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

1. Main Model

```js
{
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  carModels: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'CarModel'
  }]
}
```

2. Second Model

```js
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true
    },
    carModels: [
      {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'CarModel'
      }
    ]
  },
```

3. Third Model

```js
{
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  }
},
```

Here i am trying to insert the data like this

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "phoneNumber": "0123456789",
  "email": "m@m.com",
  "carMakes": [{
    "name": "BMW",
    "carModels": [{
      "_id": "some id"
    }]
  }]
}
```

and it giving me error like

> `carMakes.0: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value`

here is the create function

```
export const create = async data => {
  const result = await Booking(data).save();
  return result;
};
```

Can anyone tell what I am missing here ..i am learning nodejs

Comment: You're missing a function `Booking`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is with the `_id` that you're passing to `carModel` and since you set the type to `ObjectId` it has to be in a valid format "either 12 byte binary string, or a 24 hex byte string" and "some id" is not the valid one if you're sending that.

you can check if your id is valid with [isValidObjectId()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-isValidObjectId) function.

or you can easily generate an `ObjectId`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```